# Angular CDK Portal: deprecated ComponentFactoryResolver alternative

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

It seems like `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated.

I am trying to render a portal in the body (outside the application context)

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  ApplicationRef,
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  Injector,
} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { MyFilesComponent } from './my-files/my-files.component';
import { TrashComponent } from './trash/trash.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './shared/modal/modal.component';
import { ComponentPortal, DomPortalOutlet } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    SidebarComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MyFilesComponent,
    TrashComponent,
    ModalComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  private portalOutlet: DomPortalOutlet;
  private modalPortal: ComponentPortal<ModalComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.portalOutlet = new DomPortalOutlet(
      document.body,
      this.componentFactoryResolver,
      this.applicationRef,
      this.injector
    );

    this.modalPortal = new ComponentPortal(ModalComponent);

    this.portalOutlet.attach(this.modalPortal);
  }
}
```

This is working. But what to use instead of the `ComponentFactoryResolver`? When I don't pass the factory resolver to the `DomPortalOutlet` the modal doesn't show up at all.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I tried this:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor() {}

  public vcr = inject(ViewContainerRef);


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const compRef = this.vcr.createComponent(ModalComponent);
    compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

  }
}
```

It seems to work. It's simpler. But I don't understand why the modal is rendered as a child of the body. It's what I want but I didn't specify that.

Does that mean that portal from the angular cdk is not needed to dynamically inject a component anywhere in the DOM?

Comment: Anybody here??!

Comment: Unfortunately there is still an open issue for this on Github: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24334